# How to pronounce Mos Eisley?

Tags: star-wars, names, pronunciation

For several months I've been a regular participant in this site's [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley), **Mos Eisley**. But [I've never seen Star Wars](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00hcr67), so I don't know how to pronounce the name! Is it "*moz ice-lee*" or "*moss eyes-lay*" or something else?

PS. If it makes a difference, I speak British English.

<sub>PPS. Anyone who DVs me for not having seen Star Wars will get a revenge-DV if they haven't read Wheel of Time ;-)</sub>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just listen to Obi-Wan:

Let's say it together now: **"moss ice-zlee".**

Comment: Hmm, it's more complicated than I'd expected! You and @N_Soong disagree on the pronunciation (and you keep editing) - I'll hide while you fight it out :-P

Comment: @randal'thor : Hehe, just trying to perfectly capture the nuances of Obi-Wan's pronunciation. ;-)

Comment: I can't say "ice-zlee". That "szl" cluster seems impossible to me. Anyway, do we want to imitate Obi-Wan's British accent? How do the native Tatooinians pronounce it?

Comment: @user14111 : Geographically, Alec Guiness and I were born only a few miles apart, and so it's fairly natural for me...

Comment: For my money, Sir Alec's best sci-fi movie was *The Man in the White Suit*.

Comment: @user14111 : I completely agree.

Comment: I can't properly hear the 'z' on the sound clip - if it's there, it's very small and almost swallowed. I think I like N_Soong's transcription better :-)

Comment: There is no z - he says "moss ice-lee".

Comment: @randal'thor: There's definitely a "z" there.  N_Soong hears it too and his description includes a z...

Comment: @randal'thor - I hear the 'z'.

Comment: I don't hear the "z". Does whether we hear the "z" or not depend on where we're from?

Comment: @MrLister We could conduct a survey in [the real Mos Eisley](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) perhaps?

Comment: @randal'thor : You and I illustrate that the phenomenon is not necessarily tied to region, since we are both from the UK.  Although I was born near St. John's Wood in London (Alec was born at Maida Vale, close by) and I was raised mostly in the South of England...

Comment: @Praxis Are you sure Canada hasn't influenced your accent? :-) I've moved around a lot in Britain, but I think my accent is pretty south-of-England too. Maybe a bit less posh than Alec's though!

Comment: @randal'thor : Sometimes I fear so. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

## moss i-sszlee

Visit Wookieepedia:

> [Mos Eisley](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mos_Eisley) (pronounced /mɑs aɪzliː/, moss izelee,

And [here's a sound clip](https://images.wikia.com/starwars/images/0/0d/Mos_Eisley_spaceport.ogg) of the pronunciation, also from Wookieepedia.

To me it sounds more like ***'moss i-sszlee'***

As for how a native Tatooian pronounces it, [listen to Watto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCAYK8k8Qac&feature=youtu.be&t=4761) which confirms it is 'moss i-sszleee'.

Just for some background, the same Wookieepedia site describes it as being:

> located in a valley somewhere to the southeast of the Jundland Wastes[5] and roughly 80 kilometers north of Anchorhead, near the desert palace of Jabba the Hutt.

and Lando Calrissian is supposed to have said:

> "Mos Eisley is known as the galaxy's armpit. I guess there are worse parts of the anatomy where we could be stuck."

It was mentioned in Episode II: *Attack of the Clones* and seen in *A New Hope*.

Nothing can compare with [the real Mos Eisley](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) though ;-)

Comment: Wookieepedia spells it "moss izelee" but I can't hear the "z" on the sound clip, it sounds like "moss icelee" to me. So which is it, "ize" or "ice"?

Comment: @randal'thor those android reflexes come in handy ;)

Comment: @user14111: There's definitely a "z" sound, but there's a softer "s" sound that precedes it, which is why I'm going with "moss ice-zlee".

Comment: @user14111 I've added a link to how Watto pronounces Mos Eisley, the only other instance of it in the canon movies

Comment: @user14111, it's /moss ice lee/, but because the L is voiced, there's a transitional /z/ sound in there that some people hear while others don't.

Comment: So every sl word--slip, slap, slop, slope, sloop, and all the rest--has a z sound in it? Soup has a z sound because the ou is voiced, making it szoup?

Comment: @user14111: no, vowels don't affect the voicing of consonants, and initial consonant clusters are a different phonetic environment than cross-syllable concatenations.

Comment: Although I prefer your way of 'spelling the pronunciation' (which sounds like an oxymoron, doesn't it), I should probably accept @Praxis's answer as being more canonical :-)

Comment: @randal'thor at the end of the day it's up to you - no hard feelings either way!

Answer (score 2):

This is hilarious... have to try my hand.

It is somewhere between

**Moss eyes, Lee.**

and

**Mouse eyes, Lee.**

Remove any pause at the comma and you're there.

Comment: "We've captured a freighter entering the  remains of the Alderaan system. Its markings match those of a ship that blasted its way out of [Moss Eyes Lee]." **No `Z`'s**.